# abbreviation of observed power in Anova

Tags: anova, expected-value

I want to know what is the abbreviation of the observed power that I can extract from the table of F of Fisher.  This is the column near the partial $\eta$ squared.

Comment: The display of ANOVA results may differ among software implementations. Please show us an example of output, and/or specify what computer language software was used to obtain results.

Comment: ["Observed power" is a completely useless statistical concept. Don't use it.](http://daniellakens.blogspot.ch/2014/12/observed-power-and-what-to-do-if-your.html) See also [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49787/1352) and especially the Hoenig & Heisey (2001) reference.