# Post-hoc test for evaluating changes in baseline

Tags: post-hoc, ancova

I have two groups that recieved a different combination of treatment. For the first group baseline is 15.5 and for the second group it is 17.4. The difference in baseline after some time is −9.0±1.0 for 1.group and −7.0±1.0 for 2. group. What would be appropriate method for calculating pos hoc power? I found this calculator (https://clincalc.com/stats/Power.aspx), but I think it is not correct to use it as groups have different baseline values. Do you have any recommendations?
P.S I am new to statistics.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. This is not answer but since you are new to statistics, it is worth to mention: there is a strong opinion against post hoc power analysis. Please see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49772/post-hoc-power-analysis

Comment: And this: [Best practice when analysing pre-post treatment-control designs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3466/237901)