Chi-square power with (heavily) unbalanced proportions
I want to calculate the statistical power of a chi-square test with (heavily) unbalanced proportions.
I have a variable that I analysed for a sample and whose distribution I know in the population, such that:
Variable  Sample  Population
----------------------------
Low        19         288564
Medium     48         445963
High       82         891926
Highest   185         996859
----------------------------
Total     334        2623312

I saw that in R, the pwr.chisq.test(w = NULL, N = NULL, df = NULL, sig.level = 0.05) function from the pwr package allows to calculate power for chi-square tests, but I was unsure how to approach the issue of the quite unbalanced proportions across the cells (and between sample and population): do I specify N = 334 or N =  334 + 2623312, or should I approach it differently altogether?

(1) Why do you want to compute the power?   There's a clear difference among the rows, indicating no need (on that basis) to conduct a new experiment.  (2) In what sense is this "heavily imbalanced"?  The relative ranges in the two columns are not problematic at all.

(1) I have other examples where the row difference is much less clear, this was just the first example on my list. (2) I am glad to hear the range difference is not problematic. In this specific case, do I thus go with N = 334 + 2623312 or with N = 334?

You should explain why you want to conduct power analysis, as unfortunately your comment does not really clarify that. Power analysis is useful to determine what sample size you need to collect; but if you've already collected the data, what do you think it will be useful for?

Some of my chi-squares are not significant. So I want to determine whether I had enough observations to detect effects, if there were any.

I recommend reading this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49787/164936 . There are also many other threads about post hoc power analysis. In short, maybe you should give up post hoc power analysis, as it won't be more informative than the results of your tests, and rather try computing confidence intervals. Also, maybe you should give more info about your research question, and how the sample has been collected, it may be useful to give you further advice.

You may also find this blog post useful: http://daniellakens.blogspot.com/2014/12/observed-power-and-what-to-do-if-your.html

This was very useful, thanks a lot! This also helped me: https://osf.io/preprints/psyarxiv/97gpc. The reason why I did not conduct power calculations in advance to determine the required number of observations was that I did not have (direct) control over the sample size (it is real-life data dependent on the people attending certain events - with the attendance [who attends] being the phenomenon of interest itself).

However, since I may have indirect control over attendances based on the number of invitations sent out (~10% of people accept), I wonder if I can approach things differently next time: calculate the required sample size based on power estimations and multiply the required sample size by ten for the number of invitations sent out? In this case, do I have to base my estimation on the number of observations in the (expected) sample (e.g. 334), or on the number of observations in the sample and population (334 + 2623312)?

The sample size is the total of observations of the table on which you're conducting the test, but you should provide details on how you plan to conduct the test. Note that to determine the required sample size, you also have to determine the effect size you're interested in detecting ("w" in the pwr package). Also: if you already know the proportions in the population, what is the reason for sampling from this population? It hints to some information that you don't mention, but that is possibly essential to give you a correct answer - e.g. are you trying to find out if your sample is biased?

Exactly, I am indeed trying to see if the people who accept the invitation are substantially different from the population on a series of dimensions. (And I now understood the role of w and p).
